# In GoLand, how to configure Refactor - Rename to exclude coverage.html?

Tags: rename, goland

Many times when I am renaming a token, the Refactor UI includes instances in **converage.html** and other, non-Go files. I choose to Exclude them, but it makes the (small) pane busy and I might miss an actual code change

I find no configuration element addressing this, either via the Preferences or in the rename UI itself

How can I exclude non-Go files as a default

Cheers

Comment: You can exclude the whole directory from the IDE (Project View, right-click on a directory, mark as excluded), for example, directories with test files, coverage information and so on. It also will be applied to refactoring.

Comment: Yes. I want to exclude this directory by default, and exclude non-Go files in all directories